# add TMenuItem bitmap

Tags: delphi, bitmap, menuitem

I want to add a bitmap to a TMenuItem created dynamically. With this code it doesn't work, I don't have the image on my menu. What's wrong?

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
   item : TmenuItem;
   icon : TIcon;
begin
   item := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu1);
   item.Caption := 'coucou';
   icon := TIcon.Create;
   icon.LoadFromFile('d:\SmallIcon.ico');
   icon.Height := 16;
   icon.Width := 16;
   item.Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0,0,icon);
   PopupMenu1.Items.Add(item);
end;
```

Comment: Use the little `{}` toolbar button to mark code fragments. This is easier and yields better results than manually inserting HTML tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line

```
   item.Bitmap.SetSize(16,16);
```

as third one. Then it works.

So your code would look like this:

```
var
   item : TmenuItem;
   icon : TIcon;
begin
   item := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu1);
   item.Caption := 'coucou';
   item.Bitmap.SetSize(16,16);   // <--- set size of bitmap
   icon := TIcon.Create;
   icon.LoadFromFile('d:\SmallIcon.ico');
   icon.Height := 16;
   icon.Width := 16;
   item.Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0,0,icon);
   PopupMenu1.Items.Add(item);
end;
```

Although I agree with David. Better use a `TImageList`.

Comment: `TIcon` knows how to copy itself to a `TBitmap` when `Assign()` is called.  I would suggest that intead of calling `SetSize()` and `Draw()` manually, eg: `item.Bitmap.Assign(icon);`

Comment: That was my first idea but it doesn't work in Delphi 2009 (`EConvertError`). XE works though (`TIcon.AssignTo` seems to be new here).

Comment: Works fine in D2010, so it must be a new feature.

Answer (score 10):

The `Bitmap` property on `TMenuItem` isn't the way to go here.  You really should use image lists instead. This will allow you to share images between your UI elements in a manageable fashion.

1. Add the icon to a `TImageList`.
2. Set the `Images` property on the menu (i.e. `PopupMenu1`) to refer to the image list.
3. Set the image index of the menu item to the index of the icon in the list, i.e. 0 if it's the first image.

Of course, you really ought to be using actions too, in which case you simply need to set the `ImageIndex` for the action and the framework takes care of assigning it to the menu item.

As an aside, I would note that the Delphi implementation of Vista themed menus has a large number of subtle bugs, many related to drawing of images. However, these bugs are relatively minor in visual impact.

Answer (score 1):

a) You can't set TIcon dimensions once they have an image in them -- if your loaded icon isn't already 16x16 you'll get an exception, b) You don't indicate if your parent menu uses a TImageList (if so, you can't set individual images), c) by default, I don't think tmenuitem bitmaps have a particular size/color depth or anything else. You need to properly create a TBitmap to assign to the TMenuItem.Bitmap (assuming your parent menu doesn't use TImageLists).